# Why am I unable to import a module with Typescript / node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

File: util.ts

```
class Util  {
   task1 () {
        return 9;
    }
}
module.exports = new Util();
```

File: base.ts

```
// <reference path="../../Utils/util.ts" />
import util = require('../../Utils/util.js');

class child {

}
```

I am trying to import the util module but when I do this it gives me an error saying.

```
Error   1   Unable to resolve external module ''../../Utils/util.js''.  C:\Protractor\Latest\Test\Test\Scripts\Admin\Common\base.ts 4   1   Test
```

Can someone help tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here's the location of my files:

```
C:\Protractor\Latest\Test\Test\Scripts\Utils\util.js
C:\Protractor\Latest\Test\Test\Scripts\Utils\util.ts
C:\Protractor\Latest\Test\Test\Scripts\Admin\Common\base.ts
```

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - I updated the question with the locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use reference comments when using import statements and external modules, so you can remove this line...

```
// <reference path="../../Utils/util.ts" />
```

Once your import statement works, it will bring in the type information just like a reference comment. You don't need to include the file extension...

```
import util = require('../../Utils/util');
```

Let me know if you are still stuck.